# Android studio, why does progressbar disappear before asynctasks are complete?

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have the following **Asyntask** in ***Android Studio***.

I'm battling to get the progressbar to work though, the progressbar pops up but then immediately disappears. 
I want to know:

> Why is it not waiting for the tasks in the `DoInBackground` to complete before it disappears?

Any advice would be appreciated. I am a beginner so please excuse the silly question if it is indeed a silly question.
The tasks within `DoInBackground` are calls to a *volley requests*, which copy data from a remote **sql database** into the devices **sqlite database**.

Thanks.

```
public class AsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {

        ProgressBar pb;
        int status = 0;

        public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar) {
            this.pb = progressBar;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d(TAG, "zzzzz2: " + "Pre");
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }



        @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Integer[] objects) {

                Log.d(TAG, "zzzzz2: " + "DoIn");


//              if user doesnt exist in db add to server db
                String strUser = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
                String strDisplayName = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
                String strEmail = mFirebaseUser.getEmail();
                clsServerClass.addUserToServer(strUser, strDisplayName, strEmail, context);

                // load 12 tables into sqlite database
                clsServerClass.copyTblVersions(context);
                clsServerClass.copyAnimalClassTable(context);
                clsServerClass.copyAnimalGroupTable(context);
                clsServerClass.copyAnimalTable(context);
                clsServerClass.copyTblSeasons(context);
                clsServerClass.copyRegions(context);
                clsServerClass.copyCountries(context);
                clsServerClass.copyProvinces(context);
                clsServerClass.copyHotspots(context);
                clsServerClass.copyHabitats(context);
                clsServerClass.getMyPlaces(strUser, context);
                clsServerClass.getSightingsUser(strUser, context);


                Cursor cntry = getCsr("animal_unique_key", "tbl_lookup_animals");
                Log.d(TAG, "yyyya: " + cntry.getCount());

                JSONArray arrayList1 = createListArray("animal_class_key", 1);
                createListSharedPref("List1_name", "List 1: All birds", "List1_where", arrayList1);

                JSONArray arrayList2 = createListArray("animal_class_key",  2);
                createListSharedPref("List2_name", "List 2: All Mammals", "List2_where", arrayList2);

                JSONArray arrayList3 = createListArray("animal_class_key", -99);
                createListSharedPref("List3_name", "List 3: All Animals", "List3_where", arrayList3);

                JSONArray arrayList4 = createListArray("animal_class_key", 3);
                createListSharedPref("List4_name", "List 4: All Reptiles", "List4_where", arrayList4);

                JSONArray arrayList5 = createListArray("animal_class_key", 4);
                createListSharedPref("List5_name", "List 5: All Amphibians", "List5_where", arrayList5);

                return null;

            }



        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer[] values) {

            Log.d(TAG, "zzzzz3: " + "Update");

            pb.setProgress(values[0]);
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "zzzzz2: " + "post");
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }




        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem lies in onProgressUpdate method.**

**Docs**

> onProgressUpdate() : This method receives progress updates from
>   doInBackground method, which is published via publishProgress method,
>   and this method can use this progress update to update the UI thread

Since you are not passing any value to your onProgressUpdate, your progress bar disappears immediately.

In doInBackground method after `Log.d(TAG, "zzzzz2: " + "DoIn");`

**Add**

```
publishProgress(5); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
//5 is just an example integer
```

Now, it should work fine.

To learn more about how to better make use of onProgressUpdate(), consult https://www.tanelikorri.com/tutorial/android/asynctask-tutorial/